# Hiding strings from strings tool in c language

Tags: c, gcc, static, msys2

The goal is to declare char arrays that are not show when using a tool like `strings`

The approaches

```
#include <stdio.h>

// method 1 
#define PRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define PUBLIC __attribute__((visibility("default")))

PUBLIC char visible_msg[] = "can you see me";
PRIVATE char not_visible[] = "this is hidden ";

// method 2
static char secret[] = "1337h4x";

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", secret);
    printf("%s\n", visible_msg);
    printf("%s\n", not_visible);
}
```

method 2 work fine on linux but on windows this is useless code and I get the warning  `visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]` and i tried to use `-visibility=hidden` but this does not have an effect and i can still dump the strings

I am compiling using MINGW64 in msys2

Comment: *method 2 work fine on linux*  Did you try `strings -a ...`?  If the string is in the binary, it can be found.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah method 2 does not work

Comment: As @AndrewHenle points out: attempting to modify symbol visibility does not change the fact that the data are there, in the binary in plaintext. If this is being done in an attempt to increase security, other methods are needed. Either in-application encryption, or externalize the string to a file that is both encrypted and permissions-protected.

Comment: Storing encrypted strings in your executable and decrypting them at runtime can help against a simple program like `strings` but won't stop anyone from debugging or decompiling your executable to get them.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Mostly yes. There are (weak) security benefits that can make debug-time retrieval of data more difficult than offline binary inspection, for a sane OS that constrains debug permissions.

Comment: Also not shown: if this is some kind of password, the password shouldn't be saved anywhere and instead only a salted hash stored. Unclear if the situation permits this.

Comment: @Reinderien But *someone else's* system never runs a "sane OS".

Comment: There is no question in your post. Edit it to ask a specific question.

Comment: @Reinderien no this is not a password it is a string the is used by the code but the user should not see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The approaches

Neither of these approaches can work reliably -- the compiler will still put a string literal into the read-only section of the binary (at least for sufficiently long strings).

Here is an approach which hides the string from `strings`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  // "this is hidden " in ASCII
  // 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 68 69 64 64 65 6e 20
  int offsets[] = { 0x74 - 'a', 0x68 - 'a', 0x69 - 'a', 0x73 - 'a',
                    0x20 - 'a', 0x69 - 'a', 0x73 - 'a', 0x20 - 'a',
                    0x68 - 'a', 0x69 - 'a', 0x64 - 'a', 0x64 - 'a',
                    0x65 - 'a', 0x6e - 'a', 0x20 - 'a'
  };

  for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(offsets) / sizeof(offsets[0]); j++) {
    const int offset = offsets[j];
    if (offset < 0)
      putc(' ', stdout);
    else
      putc(letters[offset], stdout);
  }
  puts("");
  return 0;
}
```

You can re-order `letters[]` and/or remove unused letters to make it even more obscure.